# Jquery: 1 button for choose file and file upload?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry if this question is a bit confusing but I don't know how else i can explain it so please bear with me.

Basically, I need to use 1 button for choose file and once the file's chosen, the file gets uploaded automatically as opposed to the standard file input + submit button if that makes sense?

So the usual standard file upload is like this:

```
<form id="form" action="ajaxupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">


<input id="uploadImage" type="file" accept="image/*" name="image" />

<input id="button" type="submit" value="Upload">

</form>
```

is there any way so we can have something like this:

```
 <form id="form" action="ajaxupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="uploadImage" type="file" accept="image/*" name="image" />
  </form>
```

and once the file's chosen from that dialog box that opens after clicking on the choose file (file input), the file gets uploaded?

I've seen this done on many sites and I just wonder how they do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: not clear, can you name some site that implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code should help you fix it

```js
$("document").ready(function() {

  $("#uploadImage").change(function() {
    $('#form').submit();
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" action="ajaxupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input id="uploadImage" type="file" accept="image/*" name="image" />

</form>
```

Comment: OP don't wants submit button in form;

Comment: @itzmukeshy7, this is actually the correct answer and it worked like a charm. I just had to remove the submit button.

Comment: @LazyDeveloper can you do one more thing put a check if not file chosen then form should not submit;

Answer (score 2):

Best way to do this with preview:

```
<input type='file' />
<img id="myImg" src="#" alt="your image" />

$("#myImg").hide();
$(function () {
  $(":file").change(function () {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
      }
    });
 });

  function imageIsLoaded(e) {
  $("#myImg").show();
  $('#myImg').attr('src', e.target.result);
};
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNqPbb

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library Dropzone.js 
Click the link below 
http://www.dropzonejs.com/

Comment: I did look at that but that is not what I am after! that is a drop file plugin which is not what i am looking for. thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Add a javascript change event the file input. inside the change function do your file upload

Also set the css for the #uploadImage to hidden

ie. `#uploadimage{display:"none"}`

eg in jquery

```js
$( "#fileinput" ).change(function() {
 //do the fileupload here
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, its not a runnable code though. just wanted to explain the concept to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap, you can create beautiful single button file inputs by using the **[Bootstrap Filestyle plugin](http://markusslima.github.io/bootstrap-filestyle/1.0.6/)**.

This is one of the many effects you can create:

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

// <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-filestyle.min.js"> </script>  include this file..


(function($){var nextId=0;var Filestyle=function(element,options){this.options=options;this.$elementFilestyle=[];this.$element=$(element)};Filestyle.prototype={clear:function(){this.$element.val("");this.$elementFilestyle.find(":text").val("");this.$elementFilestyle.find(".badge").remove()},destroy:function(){this.$element.removeAttr("style").removeData("filestyle");this.$elementFilestyle.remove()},disabled:function(value){if(value===true){if(!this.options.disabled){this.$element.attr("disabled","true");this.$elementFilestyle.find("label").attr("disabled","true");this.options.disabled=true}}else{if(value===false){if(this.options.disabled){this.$element.removeAttr("disabled");this.$elementFilestyle.find("label").removeAttr("disabled");this.options.disabled=false}}else{return this.options.disabled}}},buttonBefore:function(value){if(value===true){if(!this.options.buttonBefore){this.options.buttonBefore=true;if(this.options.input){this.$elementFilestyle.remove();this.constructor();this.pushNameFiles()}}}else{if(value===false){if(this.options.buttonBefore){this.options.buttonBefore=false;if(this.options.input){this.$elementFilestyle.remove();this.constructor();this.pushNameFiles()}}}else{return this.options.buttonBefore}}},icon:function(value){if(value===true){if(!this.options.icon){this.options.icon=true;this.$elementFilestyle.find("label").prepend(this.htmlIcon())}}else{if(value===false){if(this.options.icon){this.options.icon=false;this.$elementFilestyle.find(".icon-span-filestyle").remove()}}else{return this.options.icon}}},input:function(value){if(value===true){if(!this.options.input){this.options.input=true;if(this.options.buttonBefore){this.$elementFilestyle.append(this.htmlInput())}else{this.$elementFilestyle.prepend(this.htmlInput())}this.$elementFilestyle.find(".badge").remove();this.pushNameFiles();this.$elementFilestyle.find(".group-span-filestyle").addClass("input-group-btn")}}else{if(value===false){if(this.options.input){this.options.input=false;this.$elementFilestyle.find(":text").remove();var files=this.pushNameFiles();if(files.length>0&&this.options.badge){this.$elementFilestyle.find("label").append(' <span class="badge">'+files.length+"</span>")}this.$elementFilestyle.find(".group-span-filestyle").removeClass("input-group-btn")}}else{return this.options.input}}},size:function(value){if(value!==undefined){var btn=this.$elementFilestyle.find("label"),input=this.$elementFilestyle.find("input");btn.removeClass("btn-lg btn-sm");input.removeClass("input-lg input-sm");if(value!="nr"){btn.addClass("btn-"+value);input.addClass("input-"+value)}}else{return this.options.size}},placeholder:function(value){if(value!==undefined){this.options.placeholder=value;this.$elementFilestyle.find("input").attr("placeholder",value)}else{return this.options.placeholder}},buttonText:function(value){if(value!==undefined){this.options.buttonText=value;this.$elementFilestyle.find("label .buttonText").html(this.options.buttonText)}else{return this.options.buttonText}},buttonName:function(value){if(value!==undefined){this.options.buttonName=value;this.$elementFilestyle.find("label").attr({"class":"btn "+this.options.buttonName})}else{return this.options.buttonName}},iconName:function(value){if(value!==undefined){this.$elementFilestyle.find(".icon-span-filestyle").attr({"class":"icon-span-filestyle "+this.options.iconName})}else{return this.options.iconName}},htmlIcon:function(){if(this.options.icon){return'<span class="icon-span-filestyle '+this.options.iconName+'"></span> '}else{return""}},htmlInput:function(){if(this.options.input){return'<input type="text" class="form-control '+(this.options.size=="nr"?"":"input-"+this.options.size)+'" placeholder="'+this.options.placeholder+'" disabled> '}else{return""}},pushNameFiles:function(){var content="",files=[];if(this.$element[0].files===undefined){files[0]={name:this.$element[0]&&this.$element[0].value}}else{files=this.$element[0].files}for(var i=0;i<files.length;i++){content+=files[i].name.split("\\").pop()+", "}if(content!==""){this.$elementFilestyle.find(":text").val(content.replace(/\, $/g,""))}else{this.$elementFilestyle.find(":text").val("")}return files},constructor:function(){var _self=this,html="",id=_self.$element.attr("id"),files=[],btn="",$label;if(id===""||!id){id="filestyle-"+nextId;_self.$element.attr({id:id});nextId++}btn='<span class="group-span-filestyle '+(_self.options.input?"input-group-btn":"")+'"><label for="'+id+'" class="btn '+_self.options.buttonName+" "+(_self.options.size=="nr"?"":"btn-"+_self.options.size)+'" '+(_self.options.disabled?'disabled="true"':"")+">"+_self.htmlIcon()+'<span class="buttonText">'+_self.options.buttonText+"</span></label></span>";html=_self.options.buttonBefore?btn+_self.htmlInput():_self.htmlInput()+btn;_self.$elementFilestyle=$('<div class="bootstrap-filestyle input-group">'+html+"</div>");_self.$elementFilestyle.find(".group-span-filestyle").attr("tabindex","0").keypress(function(e){if(e.keyCode===13||e.charCode===32){_self.$elementFilestyle.find("label").click();return false}});_self.$element.css({position:"absolute",clip:"rect(0px 0px 0px 0px)"}).attr("tabindex","-1").after(_self.$elementFilestyle);if(_self.options.disabled){_self.$element.attr("disabled","true")}_self.$element.change(function(){var files=_self.pushNameFiles();if(_self.options.input==false&&_self.options.badge){if(_self.$elementFilestyle.find(".badge").length==0){_self.$elementFilestyle.find("label").append(' <span class="badge">'+files.length+"</span>")}else{if(files.length==0){_self.$elementFilestyle.find(".badge").remove()}else{_self.$elementFilestyle.find(".badge").html(files.length)}}}else{_self.$elementFilestyle.find(".badge").remove()}});if(window.navigator.userAgent.search(/firefox/i)>-1){_self.$elementFilestyle.find("label").click(function(){_self.$element.click();return false})}}};var old=$.fn.filestyle;$.fn.filestyle=function(option,value){var get="",element=this.each(function(){if($(this).attr("type")==="file"){var $this=$(this),data=$this.data("filestyle"),options=$.extend({},$.fn.filestyle.defaults,option,typeof option==="object"&&option);if(!data){$this.data("filestyle",(data=new Filestyle(this,options)));data.constructor()}if(typeof option==="string"){get=data[option](value)}}});if(typeof get!==undefined){return get}else{return element}};$.fn.filestyle.defaults={buttonText:"Choose file",iconName:"glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open",buttonName:"btn-default",size:"nr",input:true,badge:true,icon:true,buttonBefore:false,disabled:false,placeholder:""};$.fn.filestyle.noConflict=function(){$.fn.filestyle=old;return this};$(function(){$(".filestyle").each(function(){var $this=$(this),options={input:$this.attr("data-input")==="false"?false:true,icon:$this.attr("data-icon")==="false"?false:true,buttonBefore:$this.attr("data-buttonBefore")==="true"?true:false,disabled:$this.attr("data-disabled")==="true"?true:false,size:$this.attr("data-size"),buttonText:$this.attr("data-buttonText"),buttonName:$this.attr("data-buttonName"),iconName:$this.attr("data-iconName"),badge:$this.attr("data-badge")==="false"?false:true,placeholder:$this.attr("data-placeholder")};$this.filestyle(options)})})})(window.jQuery);


$(":file").filestyle({input: false});
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" class="filestyle" data-input="false" data-buttonName="btn-info btn-xs" />
```